# Regex to deterime text 'http://...'  but not in iframes, embeds...etc

Tags: php, regex

This regex is used to replace text links with a clickable anchor tag.

```
#(?<!href="|">)((?:https?|ftp|nntp)://[^\s<>()]+)#i
```

My problem is, I don't want it to change links that are in things like `<iframe src="http//...`  or `<embed src="http://...`

I tried checking for a whitespace character before it by adding \s, but that didn't work.

Or - it appears they're first checking that an href=" doesn't already exist (?) - maybe I can check for the other things too?

Any thoughts / explanations how I would do this is greatly appreciated.  Main, I just need the regex - I can implement in CakePHP myself.

The actual code comes from CakePHP's `Text->autoLink()`:

```
function autoLinkUrls($text, $htmlOptions = array()) {
    $options = var_export($htmlOptions, true);
    $text = preg_replace_callback('#(?<!href="|">)((?:https?|ftp|nntp)://[^\s<>()]+)#i', create_function('$matches',
        '$Html = new HtmlHelper(); $Html->tags = $Html->loadConfig(); return $Html->link($matches[0], $matches[0],' . $options . ');'), $text);
    return preg_replace_callback('#(?<!href="|">)(?<!http://|https://|ftp://|nntp://)(www\.[^\n\%\ <]+[^<\n\%\,\.\ <])(?<!\))#i',
        create_function('$matches', '$Html = new HtmlHelper(); $Html->tags = $Html->loadConfig(); return $Html->link($matches[0], "http://" . $matches[0],' . $options . ');'), $text);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expand the lookbehind at the beginning of those regexes to check for `src="` as well as `href="`, like this:

`(?<!href="|src="|">)`